# Suggestion: Make clear at top level that a question is protected

Tags: feature-request

Sure, someone might want to read a protected question, comments, or answers to it. And someone might want to add a new comment.

But it would be helpful to know before visiting a question whether it is protected. That way, someone who might visit it to offer an answer or edit the question can know beforehand that new answers and edits are not allowed.

When a question has been determined to be a duplicate, you see **[duplicate]** in its title at the top level.  And if migrated you see **[migrated]**. Why not similarly show **[protected]** for a protected question?

Comment: What is a blocked question?  Do you mean a locked one?

Comment: I thought I saw the word *blocked* in this context, but I guess the word is *protected*. [Here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/175510/51214) is an example. I edited the suggestion accordingly. Thx.

Comment: 'Protected' only prevents answering by new users (those with rep less than 10). Do you think this feature request is worthwhile for them?

Comment: @Mitch. No; I don't think that. I misunderstood. I guess I didn't read the notice well. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: I can't imagine many (if *any*) users who don't have the necessary 10 rep points required to answer such questions would have any idea what "protected" means in this context, so I'm voting -1 because this feature seems utterly pointless to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: See my reply saying that I misread the notification.  I can delete the question if you like.  OTOH, what seems pointless to me is brandishing a giant banner saying that the page is **protected** when it is only protected against editing by users who have fewer than 10 (count 'em!) points.  Not an excuse for my misreading, by any means, but still not very good UI, IMHO.